# Server works only when listen.mode is set to 0777

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I was getting 502 Bad Gateway. I checked  and saw that the default is:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

so I changed it to

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0777
```

and now it's working. But I don't think that's right. What should I do to make it run as intended? `777` doesn't feel right here

Comment: I guess from the names the system is Debian or Debian derivative. nginx is supposed to run as www-data. So does php-fpm (except for their master process running as root for both). Is that the case in your system? If not, is something not coming from official packages?

Comment: You are right, I did not have the user declared in `nginx.conf`, after adding `user   www-data` it started working! Ty! And yes it's Ubuntu :)

Comment: Since it appears your problem is solved, you should answer your own question and mark the answer as solved, or else delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue: I did not have the user that runs nginx declared in `nginx.conf`, after adding `user   www-data` to the main section of the config file, it started working